# EXC_BAD_ACCESS/KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS during the training of a neural network

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, neural-network

I'm compiling my neural network in c99 on MAC OS X Yosemite.

gdb wasn't giving me a lot of information so I used a lot of printf to define where is my problem.
Here is what gdb is giving me:

> `entering into error output 0`
>
> `0.000000`
>
> `Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.`
>   `Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000`
>   `0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

and here is my code:

```
127         for (int k = 0; k < 94; k++)
128         {
129             printf("\nentering into error output %d\n", k);
130             printf("\n%lf\n", results[k]);
131             printf("\n%lf\n", outputNeuron[k].output(&outputNeuron[k]));
132             printf("\n%lf\n", sigmoid.derivative(outputNeuron[k].output(&outputNeuron[k])));
133 
134             outputNeuron[k].error =
135                 sigmoid.derivative(outputNeuron[k].output(&outputNeuron[k]))     *  
136                 (results[k] - outputNeuron[k].output(&outputNeuron[k]));
137 
138             printf("\n adjustWeights output %d\n", k);
139             outputNeuron[k].adjustWeights(&outputNeuron[k]);
140 
141             printf("\nerror output %d ok\n", k);
142         }
```

If you need anything more, just ask cause I think you are my last hope

edit:

```
 77     TNeuron outputNeuron[94];
 78     if (is_empty(file))
 79         for (int k = 0; k < 94; k++)
 80         {
 81             outputNeuron[k] = TNeuron_create();
 82             outputNeuron[k].randomizeWeights(&outputNeuron[k]);
 83         }
```

file is empty for now

and here is TNeuron_create():

```
 37 TNeuron TNeuron_create()
 38 {
 39     struct TNeuron This;
 40     TNeuron_Init(&This);
 41     return This;
 42 }
 43 
 44 void TNeuron_Init(struct TNeuron *This)
 45 {
 46     This->output = TNeuron_output;
 47 
 48     This->randomizeWeights = TNeuron_randomizeWeights;
 49 
 50     This->adjustWeights = TNeuron_adjustWeights;
 51 
 52     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 53         for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
 54         {
 55             This->inputs[i][j] = 0;
 56             This->weights[i][j] = 0;
 57         }
 58 
 59     This->error = 0;
 60 
 61     This->biasWeight = 0;
 62 }
```

edit 2:

```
  5 double TNeuron_output(struct TNeuron *This)
  6 {
  7     TSigmoid sigmoid = TSigmoid_create();
  8 
  9     double op = 0;
 10     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 11         for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
 12             op += This->weights[i][j] * This->inputs[i][j];
 13 
 14     return sigmoid.output(op + This->biasWeight);
 15 }
```

Comment: How is outputNeuron defined and initialised?

Comment: Is `outputNeuron` null?

Comment: There is a segment fault when i try to printf `outputNeuron[k].output`so I think the problem is on `outputNeuron` but the `hiddenNeuron`s are made the same way and it looks like there is no problem for them.

Comment: Maybe you should instrument `TNeuron_output()` and `TSigmoid_output()` with printfs.  It looks like your program is dying in one of those two functions.  Without having the full code, it's hard to say where.  `TNeuron_output` seems ok, so the problem might be in `TSigmoid_output`.  Or maybe it is `TSigmoid_create()`, but I expect that function to be trivial.

Comment: Well the problem is that these functions were working when my NN was only a XOR and I didn't make any change on these... `TSigmoid` contains only the mathematical formula that I use.